# Fill an input based on other input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-datalist

I have a form with 2 inputs, where the 1st input has a `datalist` attribute.

```
 <div class="col-xs-4">
     <input name="description" type="text" id="ajax" list="json-datalist">
     <datalist id="json-datalist"></datalist>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input type="text" name="product" />
  </div>
```

the JSON file has this format

```
[ {
        "product":"1235",
        "description":"description 1"
      },
      {
        "product":"1325",
        "description":"description 2"
      }, 
      ...
  ]
```

What I want is when the user selects one of the `description`, then the `product` to be added in the 2nd input..

here is the code for the javascript where loads the JSON file to the form

```
var dataList = document.getElementById('json-datalist');
    var input = document.getElementById('ajax');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
      if (request.readyState === 4) {
        if (request.status === 200) {
          // Parse the JSON
          var jsonOptions = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

          // Loop over the JSON array.
          jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {
            // Create a new <option> element.
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            // Set the value using the item in the JSON array.
            option.value = item.description; 
                                               //<--
            // Add the <option> element to the <datalist>.
            dataList.appendChild(option);
          });

          // Update the placeholder text.
          input.placeholder = "e.g. datalist";
        } else {
          // An error occured :(
          input.placeholder = "Couldn't load datalist options :(";
        }
      }
    };

    // Update the placeholder text.
    input.placeholder = "Loading options...";

    // Set up and make the request.
    request.open('GET', 'myfile.json', true);
    request.send();
```

How can I add the `item.product` as a value to the second input, when the `item.description` is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `product` in the data attribute of `datalist` like following.

```
option.value = item.description; //after this line
option.setAttribute('data-product', item.product);
```

And in `description` change event set `product` to second input like following using jquery.

```
$('#ajax').change(function() {
        var description = $(this).val();
        var product = $('#json-datalist > option[value="' + description + '"]').data('product');
        $('input[name=product]').val(product);
    });
```

Full `JS` code given below. Hope this helps.

```js
var dataList = document.getElementById('json-datalist');
    var input = document.getElementById('ajax');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function (response) {
        
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                // Parse the JSON
                var jsonOptions = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                
                // Loop over the JSON array.
                jsonOptions.forEach(function (item) {
                    // Create a new <option> element.
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    // Set the value using the item in the JSON array.
                    option.value = item.description;
                    option.setAttribute('data-product', item.product);
                    //<--
                    // Add the <option> element to the <datalist>.
                    dataList.appendChild(option);
                });

                // Update the placeholder text.
                input.placeholder = "e.g. datalist";
            } else {
                // An error occured :(
                input.placeholder = "Couldn't load datalist options :(";
            }
        }
    };

    // Update the placeholder text.
    input.placeholder = "Loading options...";

    // Set up and make the request.
    request.open('GET', 'myfile.json', true);    
    request.send();
    

    $(function() {
        $('#ajax').change(function() {
            var description = $(this).val();
            var product = $('#json-datalist > option[value="' + description + '"]').data('product');
            $('input[name=product]').val(product);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your `<option>` element with some other attribute that indicates the product, and then use that attribut to copy it into the second input.

```
request.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
  if (request.readyState === 4) {
    if (request.status === 200) {
      // Parse the JSON
      var jsonOptions = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

      // Loop over the JSON array.
      jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {
        // Create a new <option> element.
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        // Set the value using the item in the JSON array.
        option.value = item.description;
        $(option).attr('data-product',item.product);//THIS IS THE NEW LINE
                                           //<--
        // Add the <option> element to the <datalist>.
        dataList.appendChild(option);
      });

      // Update the placeholder text.
      input.placeholder = "e.g. datalist";
    } else {
      // An error occured :(
      input.placeholder = "Couldn't load datalist options :(";
    }
  }
};
```

And then, for copying it, if you are using JQuery:

```
$('input#ajax').change(function(){
  $('input[name="product"]').val($('#json-dataList').find('option:selected').attr('data-product'));
});
```

Comment: I am not sure this will work, I think my second snippet is wrong at some point, but I guess that this is the right way to go.

Comment: `option.attr is not a function ` says the log screen

Comment: `.attr()` is a JQuery(https://jquery.com/) function. If you can use Jquery, it simplifies a lot of your work.

Comment: @pablito.aven used the jQuery method on a non-jQuery HTML element.  The easiest fix would be `$(option).attr('data-prod',item.product);`

Comment: now I have the same message for the 2nd part.. I added it in the bootom of my page after the delcaration of jquery .

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).onchange is not a function

Comment: @Nat95 Sory, my mistake, it is `.change()`

Comment: sorry but it doesnt do anything.. :/